# How to flatten a JArray of JArray?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JArray of JArrays, but I would like to flatten it into a single JArray of JObjects. I have already implemented a foreach loop which iterates through each JArray in my JArray. I need to know how to flatten each sub-JArray into a JObject.

Here is an example:

```
[
  {
    "item": [
      {
        "fieldName": "Name",
        "value": "Andy"
      },
      {
        "fieldName": "Phone",
        "value": "678-905-9872"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": [
      {
        "fieldName": "Name",
        "value": "John"
      },
      {
        "fieldName": "Phone",
        "value": "688-954-5678"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": [
      {
        "fieldName": "Name",
        "value": "Ashley"
      },
      {
        "fieldName": "Phone",
        "value": "+44 671 542 8945"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": [
      {
        "fieldName": "Name",
        "value": "Avi"
      },
      {
        "fieldName": "Phone",
        "value": "(212)-908-7772"
      }
    ]
  }   
]
```

I would like each item to be a single JObject, resulting in the following JArray:

```
[
  {
      "Name": "Andy"
      "Phone": "678-905-9872"
  },
  {
      "Name": "John"
      "Phone": "688-954-5678"
  {
      "Name": "Ashley" 
      "Phone": "+44 671 542 8945"
  },
  {
      "Name": "Avi"
      "Phone": "(212)-908-7772"
  }   
]
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is my solution (c#, using Newtonsoft.Json)

```
public string ParserFunction(string json)
    {
        string fieldname, fieldvalue;

        JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json);

        foreach (JObject item in jsonArray)
        {
            JArray temp = (JArray)item["columns"]; //create new temporary JArray
            foreach (JObject jobject in temp)
            {
                fieldname = jobject["fieldName"].ToString();
                fieldvalue = jobject["value"].ToString();
                item.Add(fieldname, fieldvalue);
                jobject.Remove("fieldName");
                jobject.Remove("value");
            }

            item.Remove("item");

        }

        json = jsonArray.ToString();
        return json;
    }
```

Not sure if this is the most optimal way to do it, I saw an answer below which looks alright as well.

Comment: What did you try so far? Post some code.

Comment: `but I would like a JArray of JObjects` Your json is already a *JArray of JObjects* :)

Comment: I feel he doesn't know that JArray Consists of Jobjects.What he is trying somehow get the output .isn't it @jane.Anyway try looping Jaaray and make a Model class .In each iteration make one object then serialize it

Comment: Thanks, I know that a JArray is an array of JObjects. I needed C# code that would alter the the string to give the result demonstrated in the example. I edited and posted my solution above. I don't really understand why my question had so many downvotes... kind of messed up my account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var jArr = new JArray(JArray.Parse(JSON)
                .Select(x => new JObject(new JProperty("Name", x["item"][0]["Name"]),
                                         new JProperty("Phone", x["item"][1]["Phone"])
                             )
                 )
            );

var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArr, Formatting.Indented);
```

str would be:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Andy",
    "Phone": "(785) 241-6200"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Arthur Song",
    "Phone": "(212) 842-5500"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Ashley James",
    "Phone": "+44 191 4956203"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Avi Green",
    "Phone": "(212) 842-5500"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful.